# use QueryScope in Blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have define scope in model like this

```
class Station extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'st_id';

    public function scopeByDid($query)
    {
        return $query->groupBy("st_did");
    }

}
```

I can call byDid from controller but I cannot get it through blade template like this

```
@foreach ($river->stations->byDid as $didType)
....
@endforeach
```

how do I get it. Appreciate your response. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a relationship as an attribute (without `()` at the end) it means the relationship will have already been retrieved before the scope.

To get your code to work you will just need to change your foreach to:

```
@foreach($river->stations()->byDid()->get() as $didType)
```

Hope this helps!