# Using Query Scope to filter results within Laravel Blade template

Tags: model-view-controller, scope, laravel-5

I'm using query scope within my controllers in some places but now i'm trying to filter down some results within my blade template.  My model has a location which has orders. I pass the location to the blade template and then use the following:

```
@foreach( $location->orders->datesearch('delivered_at','2015-10-01','2015-10-15') as $order )
    {{ $order->order_number }}<br />
@endforeach
```

And here's an excerpt from my Order Model

```
class Order extends Model {

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Location', 'location_id');
    }

   public function scopeDatesearch($query,$datesearch,$search_date_start,$search_date_end)
       {
           return $query->whereBetween($datesearch, [$search_date_start, $search_date_end])->get();
       }
}
```

Location hasMany Orders as well.

The error I'm getting is:

```
FatalErrorException in 56b3a0ff15f6ddc28458248fd0728a27 line 5:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::datesearch()
```

I did find [this similar posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700283/use-queryscope-in-blade-template) which seems to indicate what I'm doing should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you error message, you can see $location->orders is a collection, but scope is not used in collection.
Try change you blade like this:

```
@foreach( $location->orders()->datesearch('delivered_at','2015-10-01','2015-10-15')->get() as $order )
    {{ $order->order_number }}<br />
@endforeach
```

Comment: This along with removing the ->get() from my scope solved the problem. Thanks Ray.